# CriteriaUpdate append to existing string value in postgres in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

While updating value of a column (text type in Postgres), I want to append new value to the existing value.  I am trying to do it using `CriteriaUpdate`, not sure how to achieve it.

EmployeeTblEntity

```
@Column(name = "warning_message")
String warningMessage;
```

JPA Code

```
CriteriaUpdate<EmployeeTblEntity> criteriaUpdate = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(EmployeeTblEntity.class);

criteriaUpdate.set(root.get("warningMessage"),  employeeTblEntity.getWarningMessage());
```

Above code is setting a new value in warning_message, what I want is to append new value to existing value.

Comment: I provided an answer, if it satisfy the requirement please consider to upvote and accept is as answer, otherwise feel free to leave comment.

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> **How append new value to existing value.** (then updating it with CriteriaUpdate)

You can use `concat()` api for appending new string values to desired selected path, beside this many other operations and aggregations can be achieve by [**CriteriaBuilder**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) root interfaces for different path types.

```
CriteriaUpdate<T> criteriaUpdate = criteriaBuilder.createCriteriaUpdate(type);
Root<T> updateRoot = criteriaUpdate.from(type);
Path<String> path = updateRoot.get(update_column);
criteriaUpdate.set(path, criteriaBuilder.concat(updateRoot.get(desired_column), "value"));
```

Which in your case it will look like below

```
CriteriaUpdate<EmployeeTblEntity> criteriaUpdate = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(EmployeeTblEntity.class);
Path<String> path = root.get("warningMessage");
criteriaUpdate.set(path,  criteriaBuilder.concat(path, employeeTblEntity.getWarningMessage()));
...
```